# How to Install .netcore sdk in azure batch node

Tags: azure, containers, azure-batch, linux-containers

I have .net core Console Application, which prints a basic hello world message. I have published my application to azure container registry.

my Docker File:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["ConsoleApp1.csproj", ""]
RUN dotnet restore "./ConsoleApp1.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "ConsoleApp1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "ConsoleApp1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ConsoleApp1.dll"]
```

I have created a node, please go through this image for better understanding:
[node-configuration1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JU2bO.jpg) ,[node-configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcn4j.jpg),[node-config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVrZG.jpg),[task-config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYG7u.jpg)

I am using a Linux container for integrating with azure batch, but whenever I run My task its saying to install

> ```
> It was not possible to find any installed .NET Core SDKs
>   Did you mean to run .NET Core SDK commands? Install a .NET Core SDK from:
>       https://aka.ms/dotnet-download**
> ```

[Task_issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnDyQ.jpg)

How do I install dotnet core in a linux container?

Please guide me on this, through sharing some examples.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the working directory for Azure Batch tasks is set to a path that is preset according to the job and task and in a [well-known location on the VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/batch/files-and-directories). This directory can be referenced by the environment variable `AZ_BATCH_TASK_WORKING_DIR`.

If you want to explicitly set the working directory of the container as specified by the container image/Dockerfile upon execution of the container, then you should set the `WorkingDirectory` of the [`TaskContainerSettings`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.batch.taskcontainersettings?view=azure-dotnet) object to [`ContainerImageDefault`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.batch.common.containerworkingdirectory?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Batch_Common_ContainerWorkingDirectory_TaskWorkingDirectory).

Comment: how to set the working directory of task container settings in azure batch node

Answer (score 0):

As fpark mentioned, here is the code snippet for setting the container working directory to ContainerImageDefault:

```
CloudTask task = new CloudTask(taskId, taskCommandLine);
Microsoft.Azure.Batch.TaskContainerSettings tcs = new Microsoft.Azure.Batch.TaskContainerSettings
                ("myhub.azurecr.io/image:tag"
                , workingDirectory: Microsoft.Azure.Batch.Common.ContainerWorkingDirectory.ContainerImageDefault
                );
 task.ContainerSettings = tcs;
 tasks.Add(task);
```